# Erro There are no comments for in the schema

Tags: c#, linq, visual-studio-2015

Estou seguindo um tutorial para acessar banco de dados via LINQ. No vídeo, vi uma função que me retorna uma lista com os dados do banco de dados:

```
public static List<LicitacaoOffline> Buscar()
{
      DatabaseEstoqueOfflineDataContext oDB = new DatabaseEstoqueOfflineDataContext();
      List<LicitacaoOffline> oLicitacaoOffline = 
                       (from Selecao in oDB.LicitacaoOfflines select Selecao)
                             .ToList<LicitacaoOffline>();
      return oLicitacaoOffline;
}
```

Acontece que na parte do código: `.ToList<LicitacaoOffline>();` a palavra `LicitacaoOffline` fica quase sem cor e quando passo o mouse sobre ela, vejo a seguinte mensagem:

> There are no comments for DatabaseEstoqueOfflineContext.LicitacaoOffline in the schema.
>
> Name can be simplified.

***Como resolver***?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Não seria só: `return oDB.LicitacaoOfflines.ToList();`

```
public static List<LicitacaoOffline> Buscar()
{
      DatabaseEstoqueOfflineDataContext oDB = new DatabaseEstoqueOfflineDataContext();
      return oDB.LicitacaoOfflines.ToList();
}
```